# Magento Dataflow Advanced Profile not showing error message

Tags: magento

Using Dataflow Advanced Profiles import to update products with Magento CE 1.9.2.1 and all patches installed. When I run the import, it fails, but there is no error code or message. Just HTML which if I save as html file and open in browser, it shows just Magento backend dashboard without any error code/message again. Seems like error reporting is somehow broken on this particular place or redirected somewhere ...

This is how the error looks like:

[image: Dataflow - Advanced Profiles CSV import failed]

Comment: It looks like it fails after calling "commerceextensions_productimportexport/convert_adapter_productimport::parse". You need to contact with them to get support. You can find their contact information on the user guide of their module here: http://www.commerceextensions.com/docs/extension_import_export_products_documentation.pdf

Comment: Have contacted Scott Bolasevich (creator of that module - Commerce Extensions), but he states, that it is not an issue related with his module. It is some general server issue with application/php error reporting from his point of view. As he said "its unrelated to extension that i can say for certain". Do you think he is true or not @muhammedv ?

Comment: I can not say if he is true or not until I investigate error logs. Did you check var/log/exception.log for any clue?

Comment: In var/log/exception.log there are no errors. In system.log also no errors - at least related with this module. var/report is also empty. Only in cPanel error log, there is maybe one related error:

`File does not exist: /home/muekradev/public_html/skin/adminhtml/base, referer: https://www.muekra.de/index.php/admin/system_convert_profile/edit/id/12/key/123456/`

Comment: Click on "System > Configuration" menu on Admin, under the "Advanced" tab click on "Developer" and confirm that "Log Settings" are Enabled (set to Yes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution, but not a root cause of that behavior. If I split my CSV with 10 000 products to let´s say 5 with only 2 000 products, it is working. So from my point of view the problem is number of rows in CSV file.

Comment: It may be because of maximum execution time limit in your php settings.

Comment: In .htaccess of Magento folder I have set sufficient max. execution time (should I change it somewhere else?). And this "error" appears just few seconds after start of the import process. It should be logged to error log in cPanel if I have insufficient max. execution time.

Comment: If it happens a few second after start, it shouldn't be about execution time limit, but then it may be because of memory limit. You can increase     php_value memory_limit in .htaccess file, but it may not be applied to your php settings. It is up to your hosting provider. Please check your php memory limit value with your system admin.